# Search multiple conditions on heroku. (pg database)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I created an app for posting album reviews. I added a search functionality, which works fine locally and on Heroku when I just search the review itself. I added code to search the review (description) or the album title or the artist name. The code is listed below. It works perfectly locally, but Heroku doesn't seem to like the syntax of the "OR"'s below.

How would I change the code to work both locally and on Heroku?

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    losearch = search.downcase
    find(:all, :conditions => ['lower(description) LIKE ? OR lower(artist) LIKE ? OR 
(date) LIKE ? OR lower(album) LIKE ?', "%#{search.downcase}%", "%#{search.downcase}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search.downcase}%"], order: "created_at desc")
  else
    find(:all, order: "created_at desc")
  end
end
```

Here is the Heroku error when I try to search the word "lips":

```
2013-05-16T23:31:34.160160+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/pins?search=lips&x=0&y=0" for 173.68.121.123 at 2013-05-16 23:31:34 +0000
2013-05-16T23:31:34.166682+00:00 app[web.1]: Processing by PinsController#index as HTML
2013-05-16T23:31:34.166682+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"search"=>"lips", "x"=>"0", "y"=>"0"}
2013-05-16T23:31:34.211501+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 45ms
2013-05-16T23:31:34.213600+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::Error: ERROR:  operator does not exist: integer ~~ unknown
2013-05-16T23:31:34.213600+00:00 app[web.1]: LINE 1: ...'%lips%' OR lower(artist) LIKE '%lips%' OR (date) LIKE '%lip...
2013-05-16T23:31:34.213600+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-16T23:31:34.213600+00:00 app[web.1]: HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
2013-05-16T23:31:34.213600+00:00 app[web.1]:                                                              ^
2013-05-16T23:31:34.213600+00:00 app[web.1]: : SELECT "pins".* FROM "pins"  WHERE (lower(description) LIKE '%lips%' OR lower(artist) LIKE '%lips%' OR (date) LIKE '%lips%' OR lower(album) LIKE '%lips%') ORDER BY created_at desc):
2013-05-16T23:31:34.213600+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/pin.rb:21:in `search'
2013-05-16T23:31:34.213600+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/pins_controller.rb:7:in `index'
2013-05-16T23:31:34.213600+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-05-16T23:31:34.213600+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

Comment: What database engine are you using locally?

Comment: sqlite3 - Sorry, I should have mentioned that.

Comment: What's wrong with the query when you run on PG?

Comment: It gives me the "sorry, but something went wrong" error when I try to search on the site. Everything else works great, and if I change the search code back to just searching the body of the reviews only, it works perfectly. It only breaks when I use the code that I posted. That code works flawlessly locally.

Comment: I recommend using postgre as your local database too, and then possibly using a gem like [pg_search](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search). It's pretty easy to pick up and configure. Sorry, that doesn't really answer your question, but in the long run, I think you'll be much better off

Comment: That 'sorry' error is just for the end user. To see what the errors are, tail the log in a terminal (`heroku logs --tail`) and then do the search again.

Comment: On any of those conditions, is there any column that is a different type other than string?

Comment: Also I see that your `date` column is not `lower(date)`. I tried replicating the same query and got a different error than you..`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "date"
LINE 1: ... "apps"  WHERE (lower(name) LIKE '%lips%' OR (date) LIKE...` What version of `rails` are you using? What data type is the date field? I'm assuming is datetime?

Comment: Yes, date is an integer.

Comment: I removed date from the search and it works now. That was obviously the culprit. Anyone know what I would do to be able to also search for integers?